# Problema al eliminar nodo especifico de una lista

Tags: c, nodos

Quería consultares por lo siguiente: tengo esta función dentro de un programa con listas en el cual si ingreso la lista y el numero de legajo de un alumno, debería eliminarlo, funciona bien, el problema es cuando ingreso que el alumno a eliminar es el primero de la lista, ahí después al pedir que despliegue la lista mi programa falla

```c
Node *eliminaresp (Node *Lista, int leg){
    
    Node *tmp;
    tmp = Lista;
    
    if(tmp->legajo==leg){
        
        Lista = Lista->sig;
        free (tmp);
        puts ("Eliminado con exito!");
        
    }
    else{
    while ((tmp->sig)->legajo != leg){
        tmp = tmp->sig;
    }
    Node *tmp2 = tmp->sig;
    tmp->sig = (tmp->sig)->sig;
    free (tmp2);
    }
    return Lista;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, déjame ver si entiendo: quieres eliminar una lista, pero tu código falla al eliminarla si es `head` (la primera, cabeza, etc), ¿cierto? Siendo así, veamos varias cosas:

1. `if (tmp->legajo==leg)` es `true`, desalocas la memory, pero luego haces `Node *tmp2 = tmp->sig;` estando la memoria desalocada. También, cuando se desaloca memoria, se debería poner el puntero a `NULL`.
2. `while ((tmp->sig)->legajo != leg)` ¿y cuando `tmp` sea `NULL`? Tendrás un `SEGV` error.
3. `tmp->sig = (tmp->sig)->sig;` ¿por qué usas paréntesis allí?

### Mi solución

```
/* author: Jose S. Daniel (@djose1164) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct List
{
    int data;
    struct List *next;
};
typedef struct List List;

struct LinkedList
{
    List *head;
};
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;

void linkedList_delete_list(LinkedList *l, List *target)
{
    /* Preparamos una indirecta. */
    List **current = &l->head;

    /* Buscamos en la lista el target. Claro, actualizando la indirecta. */
    while ((*current) && (*current) != target)
        current = &(*current)->next;

    /* *current tiene la address del target. Asi que la sustituimos. Con este metodo
    estamos simulando a un array. */
    *current = target->next; /* Estamos diciendo target = target->next; */

    /* Finalmente desalocamos la memoria. */
    free(target);
    target = NULL;
    
    puts("Lista elimanada!");
}

/* Test driver. */
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    LinkedList l = {0};
    List *primera = malloc(sizeof(*primera));
    primera->data = 5;
    primera->next = NULL;
    l.head = primera;

    linkedList_delete_list(&l, primera);
    printf("%s\n", l.head == NULL ? "Ciertamente!" : "Parece que no.");
    return 0;
}
```

### Resultado

```
Lista elimanada!
Ciertamente!
```

### Puntos a resaltar:

1. Tener un conocimiento decente sobre los punteros, ya que en mi snippet uso un doble puntero para hacer la indirecta.
2. Y lo más importante, tener claro el concepto de linked-list y cómo funciona, antes de querer simularlo/implementarlo en código.
3. También, si haces lo de buscar la indirecta una función, puedes añadir antes de una lista dada. Más info: [linked-list a good taste (en inglés)](https://github.com/mkirchner/linked-list-good-taste)